# Deploy NoneJS application with Docker

Tags: node.js, docker

Is it possible to develop an NoneJS application on windows (or another platform e.g. Raspbian) and deploy it on Linux with Docker?

Comment: This is a yes/no question. The answer is yes. Did you have a more specific issue that you are facing?

Comment: I would like to see an example

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you dockerize your nodejs application. [`nodejs.org` explains](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/):

- You create a new directory where all the files would live.
  (`package.json`, `server.js`, ...)
- You create a Dockerfile (in that same folder) using `FROM node:argon` which is node 4.6.1 (or another version: see [`hub.docker.com/_/node/`](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/): latest is 7.0.0)

That is:

```
FROM node:argon

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

- you build and run:

  ```
   docker build -t <your username>/node-web-app .
   docker run -p 49160:8080 -d <your username>/node-web-app
  ```

Comment: @Павел pastebin is blocked at work. Can you use github gist?